# Basic Probability/Combinatorics Question? l loaves, b buyers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

How many different ways are there to distribute $l$ loaves among $b$ buyers assuming $l > b$?

1. if minimum distribution of 0 loaves is permitted? e.g., buyer 1 hogging all the loaves.
2. if minimum distribution per buyer is 1 loaf, i.e., each buyer must get at least 1 loaf?

I'm looking for an intuitive way to think about the problem instead of just plug-in-an-equation type thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" technique.

i. $l+b-1 \choose b-1$

ii. $l-1 \choose b-1$